# Gradle command error while running gradlew bootRun command

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I am new to the gradle world so it may look very simple problem that i am facing. I am getting below error while running gradle task

gradle command=> gradlew bootRun

Java_home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181

gradle version 4.6. I tried to run this command with another version as well but gain same error.
What I am missing here?

running this cmd>gradlew bootRun

Getting below error==>

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; sup
port was removed in 8.0

**Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Program**

Comment: *What I am missing here?*: the error that you're getting.

Comment: Yes but I dont understand if I missed anything to configure. I am using windows 7. I have gradle home & java home set correctly

Comment: You're missing the point. If all you can tell us is that you have an error, without specifying **which** error, and without providing any code whatsoever, how could we possibly help?

Comment: this is the output-->Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Program